# Android: How to declare global variables error

Tags: android

I've implemented this solution in my app:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/290043

And now that I my app won't start anymore. Here from the catlog:

```
Starting activity com.example.css.cih.ActivityMain on device 015d2994a6280018
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.css.cih/.ActivityMain }
ActivityManager: Error type 3
ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.example.css.cih/com.example.css.cih.ActivityMain} does not exist.
```

I did add the manifest element as stated in that question:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.css.cih.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</application>
```

And, the class:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    public boolean isCbpProject;
    public boolean isMrProject;
}
```

I should state that the app ran as expected before I implemented that solution.

Comment: What is your main Activity's name? Is it really `ActivityMain` or the default `MainActivity`?

Comment: Hmm, do you have any `<activity>` tags inside your `<application>` tag in your real manifest?

Comment: No, there are no activities in application.

Comment: Ah, I see. I need to move the `android:name` into the activity that already existed. Thanks for the help Sam! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your existing `<application>` tags with at least one `<activity>` tag inside it.

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.css.cih.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!-- Activity declaration here -->
    <activity android:name=".ActivityMain" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "android:installLocation" in your AndroidManifest.xml.

"preferExternal" will cause the problem.Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.yourpackagename"
   android:installLocation="auto"
   android:versionCode="*"
   android:versionName="*" >
```